# How to find the constant $L_v$ that converts the units from millimeter per hour to watts per square meter?

Tags: mathematical-modeling, unit-of-measure

I am solving one problem, where the sub term contains a constant $L_v$ that converts the units of $P$ from units of millimeter per hour to watts per square meter. The following is the equation given in the paper.

\begin{equation*}
\nabla . v_1 = \frac{L_v(P-\bar{P})+ L_v(Q_{vc}-\bar{Q_{vc}})+(F_s-\bar{F_s})-\xi}{M_s}
\end{equation*}

I need this value while computing the $v_1$ term. Can anyone please help me with this. The following is the text given in the paper.

[image]

[image]

Comment: $L_v$ is not just a conversion factor, because the input (length/time) and output (mass/time^3) have different dimensions.  $L_v$ must have units of kg/(m s), but your scanned paper gives no clue as to what its numeric *value* is.

Comment: The density of water (~1000 kg/m³) and acceleration due to gravity (~9.8 m/s²) are probably involved somehow.

Comment: @Dan could you please elaborate how density of water related related with the value of  $L_v$?

Comment: @User123456: Because the paper says that $P$ is a precipitation rate, and $Q_{vc}$ is a condensation rate.  I assume that this means water.

Comment: Correction: $L_v$'s units must be $\frac{kg}{m \cdot s^2}$

Comment: @Dan can we correlate the value of $L_v$ with this answer(https://www.researchgate.net/post/How-to-convert-precipitation-flux-to-mm)?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find the answer of the problem.
\begin{eqnarray*}
1 \frac{Watt}{m^2}= \frac{1}{2454000}&=&4.075\times10^{-7} kg. m^{-2}.s^{-1}\\
&=&4.075\times10^{-7} \times 60 \times 60\\
&=& 1.4670\times10^{-3} \frac{mm}{h}
\end{eqnarray*}
So, $1 \frac{mm}{h} = \frac{1}{1.4670\times10^{-3}}\frac{Watt}{m^2}$.

Is my attempt correct?